# Apache2 disable SSL for requests from LAN

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have a linux server with 3 network interfaces, one for LAN and two for WAN (IPv4 and IPv6).
Until now apache was configured to serve the same website with a single virtual host on 80 for both **external.domain.com** (as *ServerName*) and **internal.domain.local** (as *ServerAlias*).
I have now obtained a certificate for **external.domain.com** and reconfigured the virtual host with mod_rewrite to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS. When accessing the website from the outside it works well.

However, since the website is accessed with a different hostname, I believe requests from the LAN should be served with plain HTTP.
Do I need to create a separate virtual host or can I handle everything with just one?

This is my current configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName external.domain.com
        RewriteEngine on
        ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName external.domain.com
    ServerAlias internal.domain.local
    Header always add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
    DocumentRoot /data/htdocs/site1

    <Directory /data/htdocs/site1>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1-error.log

    LogLevel info

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site1-access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

        SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/apache/external.domain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache/external.domain.com.key 
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/COMODO_DV_SHA-256_bundle.crt
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    #SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES+SHA384:ECDH+AES+SHA256:DH+AES:!RSA+AES256:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5:!DSS:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP
    #SSLHonorCipherOrder on

    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA

    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    #SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters /etc/apache2/ssl/dhparams.pem
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just configure your local DNS server to resolve external.domain.com to the internal IP address? That way the address is always the same and you need only one certificate.

Answer (score 2):

If you have different interfaces you want to behave different you should define different virtualhosts and specify the ip's for each where "needed". Scheme could go like this, or at least I find this is the simpler method:

```
<VirtualHost localip:80>
....
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost extip:80>
Redirect / https://external.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost extip:443>
....
</VirtualHost>
```